# List inside another list in jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I had three pojos i.e., EvaluationSummary,RuleCategory and EvalRule.

```
 public class EvaluationSummary {
      private String evaluationType;
      private Date evaluationDate;
      private List<RuleCategory> ruleCategories;
    }


      public class RuleCategory {
        private String categoryName;
        private int sequence;
        private List<EvalRule> rules;
      }
    public class EvalRule {
        private int ruleSeq; 
        private String ruleDescription;

    }
```

I need to show the details of RuleCategory into a table. I added a field in jasper report as a list for RuleCategory and I am able to display the values in the table. Now I am not getting how to retrieve the value from the list which is in RuleCategory. I googled a lot for solution and didn't get solution for this.

Comment: maybe with a subreport and a parameter: ``<subreportParameter name="xyz"><subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ruleCategory}.getRules()]]></subreportParameterExpression></subreportParameter>``

Comment: But I need to show ruleCategory and rules in same table.

Comment: then just make your layout display as if it was ony a single table, but in reality, it is a header + a subreport layed out to fit your needs.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685027/how-to-create-table-with-inner-rows/55685671#55685671 . It seems that your problem is very similar.